# cfexchangeconnection using current user by GetAuthUser()

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm looking at trying to show a user mail in a box. But I don't know their passwords and don't want them to login again, they're already authenticated. Can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could have the ColdFusion server use an account that has access to read other user's mailboxes. So make the Exchange connection using this generic account and then read user's mailboxes via their email address/mailbox.

Comment: I had considered that, but it sounds iffy as a security policy.

Comment: Agreed, but so does allowing users to view their email without entering a password. How are your users authenticated? I assume this is for internal users only (intranet)? Are these users part of active directory? Does the exchange server also use the same active directory? Are you using Windows IIS that is also a part of the same active directory?

Comment: Actually, yes to all of your questions; I should have specified. They are all internal users, active directory, same directory as exchange server and IIS. They are authenticated as they open the intranet page (I'm not the sys admin so I don't know exactly how that works) and then coldfusion accesses their active directory username using GetAuthUser()

Comment: Okay, that's good. Have you read through and done this - [Managing connections to the Exchange server](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-external-resources/interacting-with-microsoft-exchange-servers/managing-connections-to-the-exchange-server.html)  Hopefully that article will help you.

Comment: I think this is already set up. I can access mailboxes using cfexchangeconnection if I supply both a username and password (I tried this with my mailbox) but I can't see how to do it without a password

Comment: Read the bit about **Accessing delegated accounts** at the bottom of the article that I referenced. I think that's what you will need to do or login with some other privileged account that has rights to other mailboxes as I mentioned in the beginning.